# Using Batch file, how do I count number of occurences of a string in an XML?

Tags: batch-file

I have limited knowledge about batch file so pardon me if I ask any explanation on your answers :) Anyways, here's the problem: I have a text file that contains ISBN numbers, this corresponds on the XMLs that are saved in my hard drive. I want to know how to:

- read the text file and open each ISBN.xml
- count the number of occurences of a string I type in the batch
- the xml doesn't have any line breaks or carriage return if that's what its called, they vary sizes from 20KB to 7MB (I don't if this means something but..)
- this is the a portion of the xml that I want to find:`<related-object content-type="pdf.partial" object-type="application/pdf" specific-use="data" xlink:href="999999999999999toc_pv-viii_CBO.pdf"/><related-object content-type="image.extract" object-type="image/jpeg" specific-use="data" xlink:href="9999999999999_abstract_CBO.jpg"/>`
- then proceed to the next ISBN, repeat the whole process until the end of the text file
- then make a log of it like:

  - 999999999999999: 0
  - 999999999999998: 2
  - 777777777777562: 34

I copy/pasted some of my command on another batch file, but I can't pass any further urgh..

```
    @ECHO off

    set file_list=%CD%\count_list.txt
    if not exist "%CD%\count_list.txt" (
        ECHO Error: count_list.txt not found.
        ECHO Creating count_list.txt
        ECHO 2>count_list.txt >nul`
        ECHO Done
        ECHO Use count_list.txt to list the files to be read.
        goto :han
    )

    CLS
    ECHO 1) Count words.
    ECHO 2) Exit.
    ECHO.

    CHOICE /C 12 /M "Press a number:"
    CLS

    IF ERRORLEVEL 2 Exit
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO bilang

    :bilang

    if not exist "%CD%\count.log" GOTO :hill
    del "%CD%\count.log"

    :hill
    set /p src_folder="%~1Enter Source Folder: "

    set /p matchWord="%~1Enter string to count: "

    for /f "delims=" %%f in (%file_list%) do (
        if exist "%src_folder%\%%f*" (
        ECHO %%f Result:
        )>>xerox.log else (
        ECHO %%f does not exist
        )

        for /f %%C in ('Find /C "%matchWord%" ^< %src_folder%\%%f*') do (
            set Count=%%C
            echo Result = %Count%  >> count.log
            echo Result = %Count%
        )
    )

    :han
    pause
```

There, I really tried to make it work but that's all I've got. One thing comes to mind though. Finding all string and add a carriage return for each then use the find option to count all occurence. Is that possible? That's just my opinion. Any answer will be very appreciated, thanks guys! :)

Comment: Use either `echo Result = %%C` or `echo Result = !Count!` with [delayed expansion enabled](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: here's my edited code  for /f %%C in ('Find /C "pdf" ^< "%src_folder%\%%f*"') do set Count=%%C
     echo %%f = !Count! >> count.log
     echo %%f = !Count! it does work, but it counts per line.. How do I count all occurences in the text file?